# Add new canvas context method

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, prototype

I use the following code to make sure `resetTrasform` method is available for canvas.

```
if (!CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.resetTransform) {
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.resetTransform = function() {
        CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    };
}
```

Formerly, I used to use

```
var canvas      = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context     = canvas.getContext("2d");

if (!context.resetTransform) {
    context.resetTransform = function() {
        context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    };
}
```

but this depends on the variable `context`. If I were to name it differently, the following code wouldn't work, or I'd have to modify the if statement.

Anyway, using the prototype approach I want to define another method. I tried the following

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.newBlankFrame = function() {
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.resetTransform();
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

but it doesn't work. It throws this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

at `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.resetTransform();`

Also if I remove `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.resetTransform();` and just use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`, it still throws error: `Uncaught TypeError: CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect is not a function`.

I just want to have a method that'll remove any transform and clear the canvas. I could make it like this

```
var canvas      = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context     = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.newBlankFrame = function() {
    context.resetTransform();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

but this, like I said before, is dependent on the variable name. Is there a way to make this work using prototype? I want the method to be available for any canvas context.

Comment: Be aware that adding to the prototype of an API can make for *very difficult to find* errors. For example, your `.resetTransform` is already part of the CanvasRenderingContext2D API in Chrome and you are over-riding it with your own .resetTransform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your methods are missing the context in which they have to be called.
This can be fixed by using the `this` keyword which refers to the canvas context that you are trying to manipulate.

```
if (!CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.resetTransform) {
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.resetTransform = function() {
        this.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    };
}

CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.newBlankFrame = function() {
    this.resetTransform();
    this.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height); // canvas of the context
};
```

Here is a little fiddle to show that you can call the methods on any context now.
http://jsfiddle.net/87ac5j8w/

Comment: Derp. Haha. Should have figured `this`. Thanks.